# Incorrect sytax near '(' in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've got following error:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Line 9:
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

My SQL is:

```
USE [dbname]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[table_name]    Script Date: 10/20/2014 16:41:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sth] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [list] [smallint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_table_name] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Unfortunately I can't see any error. Moreover the script is generated by SQL Server Management Studio (click on table -> script table as -> create to -> new query window) because I want to make very table to another.

Is there something wrong in the query or maybe can it be caused by insufficient privileges (I'm not logged as the database owner or system administrator anyway I can create new table by clicking "new table" on the tables directory).

EDIT:

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 and the server is Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2187.

EDIT2:

I was trying to execute a script generated by the MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 on the SQL Server 2000. As far as I understand.

Comment: It works in [SQL-Server 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3dc50/1/0) and also [in 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dc50/1/0).

Comment: Verify that you don't have an invisible character like an accidentally typed Shift-Space gumming up the works. Copy-paste the code from this very page to verify.

Comment: What **versions** do your source and target system have? Are you trying to move a script from a e.g. SQL Server **2008** down to a **2000** version?

Comment: Jeroen Mostert - I've checked it doesn't matter.

Comment: Tim Schmelter - if it works in sqlfiddle (I didn't know it exists also for sql) I think it's fine and the problem is caused by insufficient permissions.

Comment: @Landeeyo Insufficient permissions don't cause this particular error.

Comment: A permissions problem throws a permissions error, not a syntax error.  There is something that you're not including.

Comment: Thank you marc_s! You're right.

Comment: If you have to create scripts from a existing Table/Database using SSMS for prior versions of SQL-Server you can change the serverversion for the script.    
The settings can be found under Tools/Options/SQL-Server Object Explorer/Scripting/Script for server version. http://imgur.com/sYTKGyz

Comment: Bummi - thank you a lot! please post your answer because it's the most accurate solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    sth nvarchar(200) NULL,
    list smallint NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_table_name PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

This omits all particular syntax and the special `WITH` options (that have all been given defaults anyway). This syntax is accepted by all versions and editions of SQL Server I'm familiar with. If this works, your problem is a version mismatch. If this doesn't work, your problem is probably of an entirely different nature altogether.